# Do not disturb encoded entites (wide characters) in XML::LibXML

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am trying to add an additional attribute to the existing XML node using XML:LibXML, when I trying to achieve this, all encoded entities like `&dagger`, `&para;` are converted into plain UTF-8 character. How to avoid this conversion and retain the original encoding?

XML:

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <!DOCTYPE test SYSTEM "test.dtd">
     <test>
     <name>
          <firstName>firstname&Dagger;</firstName>
         <lastName>last name</lastName>
     </name>
     <name>
        <firstName>first name</firstName>
        <lastName>last name</lastName>
    </name>
  </test>
```

Code:

```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use XML::LibXML;
  my $parser = new XML::LibXML;
  $parser->validation(1);
  $parser->load_ext_dtd(1);
  my $doc  = $parser->parse_file($instance);
  foreach my $new ($doc->findnodes('test'))
   {
    my($name) = $new->findnodes('//firstName');
    print $name."\n";
   }
```

I am getting the output `<firstName>firstname‡</firstName>` with converted encode, along with warning `Wide character in print at perlfile.pl`.

If I use encode print encode_entities($name)."\n"; with the help of `use HTML::Entities;` I can get the encoded entities but I don't want to use this since I may get a utf-8 character instead of an entity in my text. So I want to retain the text as it is in the output. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: provide the test.dtd

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT test (name+)>
<!ELEMENT name (firstName, lastName)>
<!ELEMENT firstName (#PCDATA)>
<!ENTITY dagger  "&#8224;" ><!-- dagger, U+2020 ISOpub -->
<!ENTITY Dagger  "&#8225;" ><!-- double dagger, U+2021 ISOpub -->
<!ELEMENT lastName (#PCDATA)>

Comment: add this line by importing modules. `binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';`

Comment: The reason you are getting that error message is because you didn't tell Perl how to encode the output. `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';` will fix that. (Even if you don't decode the entities, you still need to fix this bug.)

Answer (score 3):

This will probably require tweaking the serializer, if it's possible at all.

Entities are syntactic sugar and get replaced with the 'real' characters while parsing.  The entity strings `&[entity-name];` do not exist in the DOM representation.

If the output encoding (UTF-8 in your case) supports the characters natively that's what the serializer is going to write as it has no idea what the characters looked like in the source document.

I took a quick look at the documentation and didn't see anything of use for controlling entity output.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by the `expand_entities()`;

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;
my $parser = new XML::LibXML;

#for the output you need utf8 
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8'; 

$parser->validation(1);
$parser->load_ext_dtd(1);

#Use expand_entities for retain the entities
$parser->expand_entities(0);
my $doc  = $parser->parse_file("test.xml");
foreach my $new ($doc->findnodes('test'))
{
my($name) = $new->findnodes('//firstName');
print $name."\n";
}
```

[check more info](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod)